# join two tables on Column where column has value specified more than once

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have two tables with below data

table 1

```
Id   name  company
1    aaa   yyy
1    aaa   bbb
```

table 2

```
Id    designation
1      manager
1      manager
```

When I join these on ID, I get 4 rows but instead I want to get two rows.

target table:

```
Id    name     company        designation
1     aaa       bbb           manager
1     aaa       yyy            manager
```

how can I get this ?

In the example company is changed. It can remain same or it can be different.

Comment: Table 2 has duplicates which is the reason u r getting 4 rows.. use distinct instead

Comment: A column called ID should be a primary key column to avoid duplicates. Code by least surprise.

Comment: thank you guys! Well this is only for staging table . I might have several files with same data (can be different) which is generated as updated files from source. then I have to stage them and then update orginal table .

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Distinct` To eliminate duplicates

Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Id,T1.name,T1.company,T2.designation
FROM [table 1] as T1 INNER JOIN [table 2] AS T2
ON T1.Id = T2.Id
```